# Dynamically merge several CoreData databases, all with the same model, into a virtual single database

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I have looked around and couldn't find a complete answer to the following.

I am planning to build an iOS application which will handle UserData and provide SeedData via the initial bundle. There was already a useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224016/coredata-with-multiple-stores-configuration-woes) as how to use jointly two databases living in two different persistent stores. In my case, it responds to only to part of the problem.

I want to be able to provide various sets of SeedData as to allow storage space management as the dataset are rather big with especially multimedia material.

Basically the SeedData will be split according to a criteria and will be made available to download: so users can be able to download file for criteria1, criteria2 and/or criteria3 according to what they need and how much storage they want to use. The data will be provided as a .sqlite file, each of course sharing the same data model.

Now, there will be some small data overlap (cannot be avoided in my case) so it is possible that a single element be in both the set with criteria1 and the one with criteria3. Ultimately however the apps will show only a single element.

I have considered two approaches and I am unsure which road to take and opinions and advices would be really great:

1. Static merge: where one new dataset is downloaded, data are copied from the source to the apps database and then the downloaded data is discarded. I do not like this method because a) it requires double the storage space of the dataset during the load b) it is likely to be very time consuming c) as dataset are expected to be updated overtime, updates are likely to be hard to implement and would require again to download a big file and use twice as much size as the dataset itself
2. Dynamic merge: keeping multiple files in the sandbox Cache directory (like .../Cache/criteria1/*, .../Cache/criteria2/*, etc) which would allow to simply download the content of the folder when adding and removing the folder when discarding, and would simply require to create a virtual SeedData which would be a dynamic merge between several .sqlite files (dynamic merge which would discard duplicates thus resolving the overlap). Also updates would be very easy to handle as it is then only a matter of replacing the content of a folder by downloading new content. Then, as described in the link shared earlier, I would have a UserData database (which will be used r/w) and a SeedData composed of several datafile (which will be used strictly in r-only).

I have made many searches so far, but I couldn't a satisfactory way to achieve this (or I did not understand it). I am targeting iOS 7 strictly.

Thanks for helping if you can :)
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was much easier than I thought. I actually made some test and using

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:storeURL
                                    options:nil
                                      error:&error];
]
```

as many time as you have storeURL allows you to access the all table at once using a single NSFetchRequest.

Of course in case of overlaps the fetch request will need to be carved in such a way as to eliminate the duplicates (if it is what you want).